# Error in system(cmd, input = filelist, intern = TRUE) : 'zip' not found

Tags: r, path, mnist

I tried to read the MNIST database using the package `darch` and the function `readMNIST()`
It seems to work fine until I get the message:

> Error in system(cmd, input = filelist, intern = TRUE) : 'zip' not found'

I looked on the internet and found out that was because I use Windows and that it needed to add a zip-software to the path : `R_ZIPCMD`.
So I looked on the internet and downloaded and installed `RTools`, which looked like a suitable software, by using the `installr` package. R finds it , but the PATH remains unchanged when I enter:

`Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD")`

I still get `""`
It seems that I have to do it manually, could someone walk me through this for I am at a loss with all these deep manipulations !

Comment: I have Rtools installed, chose to *not* include it in my system path, so I get the same empty string from the getenv call. What if you just did `Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD="c:/path/to/zip.exe")` and tried your other stuff again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, based on my comment: whether using the Rtools' zip executable and/oor if you have another one installed elsewhere (e.g., [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/)), you can force *R* to use a specific executable with `Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD="c:/path/to/zip.exe")`. The code relying on zip should work again.

(If this is a recurring problem, you might want to put it in your `~/.Rprofile`.)